# How to create a Setup file using Install shield?

Tags: c#, sql-server, mdf

While I create setup file using Install-Shield after I installed and run the project it showing Database.mdf is read only?

My Connection string is :

```
"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=true"
```

Comment: Where is the database file located? Somewhere below ProgramFiles?

Comment: Yes sir...mdf file is atached below the prgm file

Comment: Well, did you hear about the common restrictions on windows program files folder?

Comment: Sir do you mean system ProgrammFiles????

Comment: After i installed the application,application file is located inside the system program files

Comment: And every user is allowed to **read** below %ProgramFiles% but not to **write**. %ProgramFiles% is not the right place for data files that will be modified within the normal application use case. The folder for that is %AppData% or %CommonAppData%

Comment: Sir we didn't get it...can you explain it?

Comment: Check the permissions tab for that DataDirectory folder after installation. (open explorer, locate the folder and open the properties of the folder).

Comment: Sir my connection string is :   connectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True" .It is only work in the local machine...it doesnot work in other system...showing Unable to connect to Server...